# Using a Dictionary for the DataSource with a ComboBox, DataBinding to an Integer

Tags: c#, winforms

This question has been asked and answered a 100 times by several people.  However, I still seem to have an issue.  I have a ComboBox that I have a DataBinding to a column in the database that is an Integer.   I have a Dictionary class that populates the ComboBox DataSource.  When I run the form, either nothing displays in the ComboBox or the Integer value from the database is displayed, not the "Text" from the Dictionary.   I have attached picture of the what the form looks like;

[image: ComboBox display]

Here is the code used to generate this ComboBox;

```
   public static SortedDictionary<int, string> SecurityCodes()
    {
        SortedDictionary<int, string> SecurityCodes = new SortedDictionary<int, string>
            {
                {1, "View only"},
                {3, "Print reports"},
                {4, "Post changes"},
                {5, "Edit records"},
                {6, "Revise postings"},
                {7, "Add records"},
                {8, "Remove postings"},
                {9, "Supervisor"},
                {10, "Programmer"}
            };

        return SecurityCodes;
    }


        this.cboSecurity.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.loginInfoBindingSource, "Security_Level", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

        this.cboSecurity.DataSource = new BindingSource(BaseDictionaries.SecurityCodes(), null);
        this.cboSecurity.DisplayMember = "Value";
        this.cboSecurity.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Now if I change the DataBinding to "ValueMember" instead of "Text", the text will display, but it does not update when you navigate to another record, it always remains on the first item of the Dictionary.  If I change the DataBinding to a View that has matching entries for what is in the Dictionary, then the appropriate "Text" is displayed in the ComboBox with the DataBinding set to "Text".  Which is okay, but then I have to maintain a table in the database with just these entries and I would prefer not to go that route.

Can anyone see what I done wrong?

I have tried many different types of DataSource combinations, including the following, with no change in the behavior;

```
        SortedDictionary<int, string> loDataSource = BaseDictionaries.SecurityCodes();
        KeyValuePair<int, string>[] kvp = new KeyValuePair<int,string>[loDataSource.Count];
        loDataSource.CopyTo(kvp,0);
        new BindingSource(kvp, "Key");
        this.cboSecurity.DataSource = kvp;
```

Comment: Can't remember the values off the top of my head, But when you bind to key / value. On the right there's  drop down for when, you need to select the other one, PropertyChanged I think.

Comment: Just copy pasted your code and it works fine, apart from ".DataBindings.Add(" as I have no idea what "loginInfoBindingSource" is. But the combobox displays the items correctly

Comment: Have you tried: ` this.cboSecurity.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue",......`

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - If you expand the slider, you will see that I have already used the "PropertyChanged" setting.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 - loginInfoBindingSource is the BindingSource in my dataset that connects to the back end database.  As you can see form the graphic, the drop down populates just fine, but I want to Bind the Key to the column "Security_Level" in the database.  When I do this, the Key is displayed, not the Value.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 - And yes, I have tried "SelectedValue" and it did not work either.  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could only make this work by using the "text" value.   Trying "SelectedValue" and "ValueMember" would not resolve the problem.   When I have time and figure this out, I will post another response.